# Breadcrumb no se encuentra con el nombre

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Estoy trabajando con [Breadcrumb](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs) el cual lo hago de la forma dinamica

tengo breadcrumbs.php

```
<?php // routes/breadcrumbs.php
use Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\Breadcrumbs;
use Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\Generator as BreadcrumbTrail;

Breadcrumbs::for('dashboard', function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) {
     $trail->push('Dashboard', route('dashboard'));
});

Breadcrumbs::macro('resource', function (string $name, string $title) {
    // Home > Blog
    Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}", function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) use ($name, $title) {
        $trail->parent('dashboard');
        $trail->push($title, route("{$name}"));
    });
});

Breadcrumbs::resource('users', __('Users'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('profile.show', __('Profile Information'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('areas', __('Areas'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('clients', __('clients'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('functionaries', __('functionaries'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('categories', __('Categories'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('type.activities', __('Activities'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('means.request', __('Means Request'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('activity', __('Activity'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('categoryofarea', __('Category of Area'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('activitycategory', __('Activity Category by Area'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('registeractivity', __('Activity Register'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('registeractivity.create', __('Activity Register'));
Breadcrumbs::resource('registeractivity.detail', __('Detalle Register'));
```

y mi vista header-breadcrumb.blade.php

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="h5 breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}"><i class="mr-2 fe fe-home fs-14"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="h5 breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
        {{ ($breadcrumb = Breadcrumbs::current()) ? "$breadcrumb->title" : '' }}
        {{ ($page = (int) request('page')) > 1 ? "Page $page" : '' }}
    </li>
</ol>
```

mi web.php

```
Route::get('/registeractivity/detail/{detailid}', DetailRegisteractivities::class)->name('registeractivity.detail')->middleware('translate');
```

todo se encuentra funcionado bien pero cuando quiero entrar a un registro detalle
me saca el siguiente error

```
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: registeractivity.detail] [URI: registeractivity/detail/{detailid}] [Missing parameter: detailid]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\consultec2\resources\views\layouts\admintro\header-breadcrumb.blade.php)
```

intente agregar lo siguiente breadcrumbs.php

```
Breadcrumbs::for('registeractivity.detail', function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail, DetailRegisteractivity  $detailid) {
    $trail->parent('registeractivity');
    $trail->push( $detailid->title, route('registeractivity.detail', $detailid));
});
```

pero me da el siguiente error

```
Argument 2 passed to Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\ServiceProvider::{closure}() must be an instance of App\Models\registeractivity\DetailRegisteractivity, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\consultec2\vendor\diglactic\laravel-breadcrumbs\src\Generator.php on line 64 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\consultec2\resources\views\layouts\admintro\header-breadcrumb.blade.php)
```

ya no se que hacer si alguien me puede decir como corregir este error.
Gracias

add controlador...

Coloco parte de mi controlador DetailRegisteractivities que creo que es relevante ya que en la variable $detailid estoy recibiendo el ID del registro

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire\Registeractivity;
    
    use Livewire\Component;
    use App\Models\registeractivity\DetailRegisteractivity;
    use App\Models\registeractivity\Registeractivity;
    use Livewire\WithPagination;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
    
    class DetailRegisteractivities extends Component
    {
        use WithPagination;
        protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';        

        public $perPage = 25;
        public $sort= 'id';
        public $direction = 'desc';
        public $updateHomework = false;
        // public $queryString = ['search' => ['except' => '']];
    
        protected $listeners = ['render' => 'render', 'destroyHomework', 'statusActivity'];
    
    
        public $detailid;
    
        public function mount($detailid)
        {
            $detailid =  Crypt::decrypt($detailid);
            $this->detailid=$detailid;
    
        }
}
```

Comment: supongo que de todos el único que recibe un parámetro es `Breadcrumbs::resource('registeractivity.detail', __('Detalle Register'));`. Si esto es cierto no lo puedes trabajar con `Breadcrumbs::macro` porque este solo rutea por el nombre sin pasar parametro alguno. Por eso te dice `Missing Parameter`. Por lo tanto, debes reemplazar esta linea por `Breadcrumbs::for` tal como lo intentaste. Ahora todo depende de que tipo de dato espera el `controlador` . Por el segundo mensaje de error supongo que espera un tipo `DetailRegisteractivity`. Confirmame paraponer la respuesta.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich ya añadí parte del controlar a ver si te sirve

Comment: Mira en `breadcrumbs.php` comenta la última línea y agregas el `Breadcrumbs::for` que hiciste pero esta vez no le pongas tipo a $detailid, es decir, déjalo así: `Breadcrumbs::for('registeractivity.detail', function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail,   $detailid) {
    $trail->parent('registeractivity');
    $trail->push( "Titulo", route('registeractivity.detail', $detailid));
});`. Debe funcionar

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich gracias, si funciona pero no como pesaba, primero como hago para colocarle un titulo de acuerdo a la descripción de la actividad, y lo otro es que solo me sale para volver a la dashboard y no al la tabla de registeractivity

Comment: Mira te pongo como respuesta esto junto con lo del título y luego vemos lo de la navegación que posiblemente es otro tema y habría que ver algun otro fuente te parece?

Answer (score 2):

La definición del route establece que  `registeractivity.detail` identica  a la ruta  `/registeractivity/detail/{detailid}`. Esta ruta tiene un parámetro `detailid`.

```
Route::get('/registeractivity/detail/{detailid}', DetailRegisteractivities::class)->name('registeractivity.detail')->middleware('translate');
```

Por otro lado los breadcrumbs definen la `Breadcrumbs::macro('resource', function (string $name, string $title)` para definir cada `breadcrumb`. Esta macro recibe como parámetros el titulo el nombre del `route`. Sin embargo, la macro no considera rutas con parámetros.

```
Breadcrumbs::macro('resource', function (string $name, string $title) {
    // Home > Blog
    Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}", function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) use ($name, $title) {
        $trail->parent('dashboard');
        $trail->push($title, route("{$name}"));
    });
});
```

Como se puede observar para `el` push`para`registeractivity.detail` omite el parámetro. Esto se soluciona agregando un parámetro opcional a la macro:

```
Breadcrumbs::macro('resource', function (string $name, string $title, $detailid = null) {
    // Home > Blog
   
   if ($detailid) {
        Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}", function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) use ($name, $title,$detailid) {
            $trail->parent('dashboard');
            $trail->push($title, route("{$name}",{$detailid}));
        });
   }
   else {
        Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}", function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) use ($name, $title) {
            $trail->parent('dashboard');
             $trail->push($title, route("{$name}"));
        });
    }
});
```

No obstante esta definición el `parent` siempre es el `dashboard` y en nuestro caso es `registeractivity`. Para ello, debemos agregar otra variable opcional (para no impactar a otras definiciones) que contenga el antecesor:

**VERSION FINAL**

```
Breadcrumbs::macro('resource', function (string $name, string $title, $parent=null, $detailid = null) {
    // Home > Blog
   
   if ($parent && $detailid) {
        Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}", function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) use ($name, $title,$parent, $detailid) {
            $trail->parent($parent);
            $trail->push($title, route("{$name}",{$detailid}));
        });
   }
   else {
        Breadcrumbs::for("{$name}", function (BreadcrumbTrail $trail) use ($name, $title) {
            $trail->parent('dashboard');
            $trail->push($title, route("{$name}"));
        });
    }
});
```

Finalmente tenemos que cambiar el `readcrumb` para `registeractivity.detail` que incluya al padre y al parametro.

```
Breadcrumbs::resource('registeractivity.detail', __('Detalle Register'),'registeractivity','$detailid' );
```

Nota: por alli pueda que algún error de sintaxis.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me sigue saliendo ..... Dashboard -> Detalle Register y debería salir Dashboard -> Registro de actividad -> Detalle Register, como podria arreglar para que me salga de esa forma.

Comment: bueno colocque la VERSION FINAL y el Breadcrumbs::resource('registeractivity.deta..... y coloque la ultima actualizacion y me sale $breadcrumbs is undefined

Comment: al definir el $breadcrumbs = Breadcrumbs::generate(); en el breadcrumbs.php me vuelve a error inicial, disculpa mi ignorancia y me novatada, donde tendría que definir el ultimo código

Comment: Mira, está pregunta realmente ya fue resuelta y ahora estamos en otro problema que está fuera del alcance del problema planteado y quizá me observen por atender un problema que no es derivado del problema planteado y esa no es la idea. Deberías abrir otra pregunta con respecto ya a la navegación del breadceumb. . Creo que mi respuesta atendió las dificultades que tuviste. Abre otra pregunta y continuamos por ese lado.BEstoy retirando lo último por lo indicado.

Comment: OK gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que **uses este paquete**.

https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

*Es mejor que intentar crear tu propia localización.*

De todas formas intenta usar un **url defaut.**

```
URL::defaults([
    'locale' => app()->getLocale()
]);
```

Documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#default-values